What options one has to fight the injustice of authorship credit denial?
A graduate student left a research group after creating a novel method, and proving it for the first time. She wrote all of the code for this, and has many presentations, plots, and tested data samples proving contributions. Her work was presented at two collaboration meetings before they left, and the student was poised to be first author on a paper in the top journal in her field regarding the work. Upon leaving the group, she had an agreement with the PI to finish out this work and train incoming students on how to take over the project.
However, directly after leaving the group, the PI then withdrew this agreement, and did not allow her to finish the work. The PI rewrote the code, although it accomplishes the same method that the student created. The student has evidence of all of this.
This work was then published in the top journal in her field, without her name on the author list.
The student has talked to a few trusted professors in the field, who all agree that this was retaliation for her leaving the research group. However, due to the power dynamics between graduate students and PIs, she fears that  pursuing this publicly will damage her reputation at the moment.
Evidence of Authorship

plots proving that she made driving contributions to 1/3rd of the figures published
correspondences with the PI proving that she was prevented from finishing out her work
GitHub histories and code accomplishing the original idea that was published

Open Questions

Is the PI correct that the students name should not be on the paper, given that the code was rewritten?
The student, also, was not given the chance to contribute to the manuscript, despite her ideas and research being core components of the paper. Should her name still be on the author list, even though she did not contribute to the manuscript?
Please recommend what the best course of action is for the students future career?


I've voted to close this as the main question (Do I have a strong case here?) is impossible to answer at a distance, since we only see what you have written. You have options, but the outcome could be anything from something satisfactory to you to a lawsuit or being labelled as a crank. You need professional advice and probably supporters/advocates.

What domain is this? The customs for authorship vary wildly, from having-written-some-code-used-for-results-in-paper to having-written-substantial-part-of-paper-prose.

But, if what you say is true, and I don't doubt you, then you have been done an injustice.

What precisely has this ex-advisor told you when you met to reconcile the situation? The additional info is important.

Why did you leave the group?

No matter what else: if the idea stems from OP, what these guys did is plagiarism, plain and simple. Even if they rewrote code, that may give them copyright, but does not change the origin of ideas. As to how to proceed to safeguard your future career, that's a different matter, and there are some relevant answers. The facts remain that OP should be at the very least co-author if not first one.

I suspect that they are minimizing the extent of your contributions, and you are underestimating the negative impact of your quitting and the amount of work still to be done on the project when you left it: that seems to be the natural process of things in these situations. Even now you're only claiming ownership over 1/3rd of the figures.
I understand there was some agreement, but also you left, seemingly by your decision. I think it's not reasonable to expect that you would be as efficient working on this project before leaving as after, and hard to predict whether you would actually see it to completion, so I can very much understand your former advisor wanting to pass the project off to someone else.
That said, authorship is at least as much about ideas and approaches as it is about physical products like code, data, and words written. I think most likely you were treated unfairly and should have been offered authorship even if much of the work was redone after you left. Your advisor should have probably had another discussion with you about passing the project off that would have involved acknowledging you would no longer be a "first" author but could be a contributing author for the work you had already done at that point.
If the institution cares about these things, you could submit a complaint to them about academic misconduct; each institution will have their own procedure and initial point of contact for that procedure. But, ultimately, it's unlikely to benefit you all that much. If you're successful, probably the professor will have some admonishment placed on their record. The paper may be retracted. Neither of those things are something for you to place on your CV. There's a distant possibility the paper could be re-submitted with you as an author, but that would require cooperation with a bunch of people you will have just seriously angered: I wouldn't bet on it, and if it were it's not going to be in the same journal, and you're not going to be first author because you only contributed to at most 1/3rd of the paper.
Maybe it's worth it just to "stick it" to the boss who mistreated you, but there is also likely to be collateral damage to other students who took over the project after you left and likely were not involved in the decision to leave you off the paper.
It's also possible the institution won't want all that mess and they'll find against your complaint when given any shred of doubt in evidence and not wanting to wade deeply into technical details outside the expertise of the judging committee: it's bad press for the institution, they likely feel more beholden to the professor than you however independent the disciplinary process is meant to be.
I have to say, it's deeply unsatisfying writing this answer. I want to say that there is a way to make things fair, but often unfortunately there really is not, and yes, this does let some people get away with things who choose to take advantage. Perhaps for a serial offender some of the balance shifts. Overall, for authorship it is much easier to make things right earlier in the process; waiting until after a publication is out there in a good venue is just too late. I understand that in these circumstances you likely just weren't involved closely enough to be aware what was happening but also, that kind of hurts your case: a lot of work was done to get this paper published after you stopped working on it. Your contributions were important, but you didn't do the whole thing. In my experience it's common for the last 5% of a paper to take at least as much work as the first 50%. Hopefully you'll find some further work to do that interests you and can get proper credit for bringing that work to completion.

This is a good answer, but in this case OP has lots of evidence to back up their claims, so there is a reasonable chance the institution's complaint procedure will work properly and things will be made fair. And if I was a student who took over the project after OP left, I would not be angry at OP at all for making a formal complaint. When the PI decided to exclude OP, I might even have strongly objected to this. So the PI will be seriously angered but the other authors might not be.

This is a good answer, but I don't really see the need for so much emphasis on the point in the first two paragraphs. Yes, having someone leave might cause all sorts of problems the OP might not be aware of, but so what? It's still misconduct to cut them out of the authorship, the circumstances don't offset that at all.

@N.Virgo They shouldn't have been left out of authorship, no, I think I made that clear, but they also didn't stick around to finish the project and the lab decided to redo everything instead. Maybe they did that just to spite OP. Probably they did it because it wasn't anywhere near done.

@toby544 How do you think it will be made fair? What will fair look like? It doesn't just involve the institution it involves the journal too. The journal isn't likely to go along with retracting the old and accepting automatically a new version of the paper, it's just going to be retracted, still without OP's name on it.

I don't know exactly. Maybe the journal might publish a note. I just had in mind the institution judging that OP was wrongly excluded. As you say, maybe that won't result in the wrong being fully put right.

I am sorry to hear it happened to you. Academia can be cruel, toxic and unfair, both due to personal egos and external pressures. From what you describe, it's clear that your contribution has not been acknowledged and that the PI treated you unfairly and used their more senior position unethically and in bad faith. I hope it won't prevent you from continuing your research elsewhere.
Academia is very hierarchical, and many critical decisions are made behind closed doors. It is not uncommon to hear that universities protect the wrong-doers because they are more concerned with maintaining the status quo than with improving the environment for everyone. If you decide to take on this fight, keep in mind, that it might damage your future academic career, even though you are right and have sufficient proof of this fact.
You have the following options:

Do nothing, leave it behind, continue your research elsewhere.
Inform the University research ethics team and provide them with the facts of the matter. You have been sidelined for the authorship you deserve, promises were broken and your research ideas have been effectively stolen.
Inform the  Head of the Department (School) the PI belongs to.
Inform the funders of the research (grant awarding bodies), who may "encourage" the University to conclude investigation properly.
Inform the journal that your research has been effectively plagiarized by the PI. The fact that the code has been rewritten is not very relevant --- the ideas behind research matter much more than the code itself.

I do not think that taking this case to a court of law is a good idea. If you do this, the University's first priority will be protecting itself, rather than investigating the case. Considering that your research ideas have not been published, you probably do not have formal rights that are protected by law (IANAL though). This does not, however, mean that you have not been wronged here --- stealing ideas is unethical and wrong, but this is something the University will be able to investigate much better than the court of law.
